# Soot - Get JimpleBody from a CFG

Tags: java, static-analysis, code-analysis, control-flow-graph, soot

I'd like to get `UnitGraph` from a Java Class.
I load it by `ClassFile` and get the `method_info` of `main()`.
Then I create a `CFG` and try to convert it into a `UnitGraph`.
My method is to get `JimpleBody` of the `CFG` and then create a `UnitGraph`.
However, I can't get `JimpleBody` by invoking `cfg.jimplify(...)` since it throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: no method associated w/ body
    at soot.Body.getMethod(Body.java:137)
    at soot.coffi.CFG.jimplify(CFG.java:814)
    at com.LiveVariableAnalysis.main(LiveVariableAnalysis.java:151)
```

My code is as follows:

```
        String mainClassName = "Calculate";
        String mainClassPath = String.format("./target/test-classes/%s.class", mainClassName);
        ClassFile mainClassFile = new ClassFile(mainClassName);
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(mainClassPath);
        mainClassFile.loadClassFile(is);
        logger.info(String.format("Loading Class: %s ...", mainClassFile));

        method_info methodInfo = null;
        for (method_info method: mainClassFile.methods) {
            if (Objects.equals(method.toName(mainClassFile.constant_pool), "main")) {
                methodInfo = method;
            }
        }
        logger.info(String.format("Loading method_info: %s ...", methodInfo.toName(mainClassFile.constant_pool)));

        mainClassFile.parseMethod(methodInfo);
        CFG cfg = new CFG(methodInfo);

        JimpleBody jimpleBody = new JimpleBody();
        // Error occurs here
        cfg.jimplify(mainClassFile.constant_pool, mainClassFile.this_class, mainClassFile.bootstrap_methods_attribute, jimpleBody);

        UnitGraph unitGraph = new ClassicCompleteUnitGraph(jimpleBody);
        logger.info(String.format("Creating unitGraph with %d units ...", unitGraph.size()));
```

I know there are other ways to create a `UnitGraph`, such as:

```
        String mainClassName = "Calculate";
        SootClass mainClass = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport(className);
        Scene.v().setMainClass(mainClass);
        soot.Main.main(args);
        SootClass mainClass = Scene.v().getMainClass();
        String methodSignature = "void main(java.lang.String[])";
        SootMethod mainMethod = mainClass.getMethod(methodSignature);
        Body jimpleBody = mainMethod.retrieveActiveBody();
        UnitGraph unitGraph = new ClassicCompleteUnitGraph(jimpleBody);
```

However, in this way, I need to set `Scene.v().setSootClassPath(path)` for `jce.jar` and `rt.jar`, which I don't want to occur in my code. So if there is another way I can get `UnitGraph` without setting such a path, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I still can't turn `method_info` into a `SootMathod` and then get a `UnitGraph`, I can use `Options.v().set_prepend_classpath(true)` to avoid set `jce.jar` and `rt.jar` dirctly. This also achieves my goal.